# Navigate With Menu (xaml)

Tags: xaml, menu, menuitem

I have 3 windows (Mainwindow, Lineup and Ticket)

How can i click on a menu or menu-item so it will navigate to another Window say Lineup?

If anyone can tell me the same thing with buttons it's also okay.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

To navigate from one window to another in WPF in the Button Click event you can add the following code

Here as you have  3 window like Mainwindow, Lineup and Ticket

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            Ticket ticket= new Ticket();
            ticket.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
  <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20">
            <MenuItem Header="Goto Lineup" Click="MenuItem_OnClick">

            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

 private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var LinUpWindow = new Window();
            LinUpWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
```